# Shortcut Badger library don't show up badge count on the app icon in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I am not able to put a badge counts on my app developed through android studio.

Actually ,i want to add number of badge count which will be equal to number of notification which i get from Google Cloud Messaging service and after reading the notification the badge count should disappear from the app icon.

So to achieve it,after long surfing i landed to a library called ShortcutBadger from git hub which will provide the functionality of showing badge count on app icon manually. So i tried it in my project and code is shown below:-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);





            try {
                int badgeCount = 4;

                ShortcutBadger.setBadge(getApplicationContext(), badgeCount);
                System.out.println("setbadge");

            } catch (ShortcutBadgeException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
```

}

the Shortcut Badger jar file can be found here :- [its from github click me](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger/tree/master/ShortcutBadger/src/main/java/me/leolin/shortcutbadger)

Now on running the project i did not get any exception and its running on my Sony xperia fine but i did not get to see any badge count as 4 on my app icon.

my terminal message show like below:-

```
04-11 11:40:37.353  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
04-11 11:40:38.503  19207-19207/com.badger.badge I/System.out﹕ setbadge
04-11 11:40:38.543  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
04-11 11:40:38.553  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_adreno200.so
04-11 11:40:38.563  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_adreno200.so
04-11 11:40:38.563  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/libEGL﹕ loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno200.so
04-11 11:40:38.623  19207-19207/com.badger.badge I/Adreno200-EGLSUB﹕ <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
04-11 11:40:38.643  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5c830000 size:26263552 offset:22495232 fd:64
04-11 11:40:38.643  19207-19207/com.badger.badge E/﹕ Can't open file for reading
04-11 11:40:38.643  19207-19207/com.badger.badge E/﹕ Can't open file for reading
04-11 11:40:38.653  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
04-11 11:40:38.733  19207-19207/com.badger.badge D/memalloc﹕ /dev/pmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5e34a000 size:37519360 offset:33751040 fd:67
```

Comment: Which launcher?  Which Android version?  The logcat you've posted is just a random snippet.  Are you seeing an error?

Comment: no i don't.launcher is android studio with apk version 15.the logcat which i posted is when my app runs its not random

Comment: yes my launcher is Sony Ericsson and it do support i read in readme. well i got the solution it was due to i was not giving my app permission to read nad write which is why i was getting could not read file in my logcat so i googled and added the user permission in my manifest.xml and then the badge has showed up. well its not we should stick to one point bro there could be some basic  problems also which you should be able to detect and learn it.

Answer (score 1):

i got the solution actually i was not giving permission to badger to read or write to my phone that is sony Ericsson so you need to paste the below permission in your manifest.xml and problem solved bingo...

```
 <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE" />
```